# Why is induction not necessary to prove this First-order validity statement?

Tags: logic, induction, first-order-logic, model-theory

I have seen the following kind of proof of the first-order validity of $(\forall x_n \varphi) \to \varphi$, where $\varphi$ is an arbitrary formula of some first-order language $\mathcal{L}$:

Suppose $\mathcal{A}, \beta \models \forall x_n \varphi$ and $\mathcal{A}, \beta  \not\models \varphi$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is an $\mathcal{L}$-structure with universe $A$ and $\beta$ a variable assignment. Then for all $a \in A$, $\mathcal{A},\beta[a/x_n] \models A$ and $\mathcal{A},\beta \not\models A$. Take the element $c$ such that $\beta (x_n) = c$, so that $\beta[c/x_n] = \beta$. Then $\mathcal{A},\beta[c /x_n] \not\models A$, so that we have some $a \in A$ for which $\mathcal{A},\beta[a /x_n] \not\models A$. Contradiction! So $\mathcal{A}, \beta  \models \varphi$

I understand the general logic of this argument, but there is one small thing about it which I don't understand. Why is it not necessary to do induction on the structure of the formula $\varphi$?

---

Put it this way, before I saw the proof above, I would have begun to do a proof by induction. *What would have been telling me that that was the wrong way to go? How could I have known that the solution would not depend on the structure of $\varphi$, when trying to attempt the proof?* I thought that whenever we have to prove some property of an arbitrary formula $\varphi$ we have to prove it by induction on the structure of the formula.

Comment: Some of your notation is not main stream, e.g. $∀ x_n$ (why $x_n$?), $\mathcal{A}, \beta \models$ (what is $\beta$?), $\mathcal{A},\beta \models A$. What is your source?

Comment: B.t.w. an argument is "good" if it succeed to convince most experienced mathematicians. (In other words, the proof of the pudding is in the eating). There is no other rule.

Comment: @PrimoPetri This $\x_n$ notation occurs frequently in "low-level" mainstream introductions to logic. Some textbooks start with a countably infinite set of variable symbols, and fix them as $x_0, x_1, \dots$ in an attempt to be more specific.

Comment: Why do you think that the above proof must be "fixed"?

Comment: @Primo Petri, $\beta$ is a variable assignment, as I wrote in the question and $x_n$ a variable. The variables are enumerated with numbers as a subscript. That is fairly standard.

Comment: @Mauro Allegranza, I've explained that. I don't understand why it is sufficient to give a proof of that form. If we are trying to prove something of an arbitrary formula $\varphi$, why aren't we thereby forced to use induction on the structure of the formula? That is what I asked in my question. Now some sensible.answers please

Comment: @Z.A.K the convention of subscripting variables with numbers is used in David Marker's "Model theory" and in Bell and Slomson's "Models and Ultraproducts", texts which can hardly be described as "lowe-level".

Comment: Because the result does not depend on the structure of the sub-formula.

Comment: To give more detail, I suppose my confusion arises because of something which I thought must be true, which is that whenever we have to prove some property of an arbitrary formula $\varphi$ we have to prove it by induction on the structure of the formula $\phi$. This therefore makes me puzzled when I see an argument purporting to show something in general about formulas, which does not have this inductive structure.

Comment: A good answer to my question would therefore carefully explain why a proof by induction is not necessary in all cases in which we are trying to show some property holds of an arbitrary formula

Comment: Ok, and how am I supposed to know when the structure of the formula is relevant, and when it is not, when proving some statement holds about an arbitrary formula?

Comment: Put it this way, before I saw the proof above, I would have begun to do a proof by induction. What would have been telling me that that was the wrong way to go?

Comment: I'm going to edit my question making this crystal clear. Hopefully then I will get some more detailed answers

Comment: @Edward.Lin No, Marker certainly doesn't fix a set of variable symbols $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n, \dots$ to be used consistently and exclusively throughout the text. E.g. he writes $\forall x. \forall y. \delta(x+y) = \delta(x) + \delta(y)$ when stating a differential field axiom, even though $x$ and $y$ are not symbols of the form $x_n$ for any $n$. This is a good thing (in particular, it's readable). There are some low-level (nitty-gritty) introductions to logic where the author would write e.g. $\forall x_2. \forall x_5. \delta(x_2+x_5) =\delta(x_2)+\delta(x_5)$ to stick close to the formalism.

Comment: He actually does when he defines the set of variables. Now please answer my question. Thanks

Comment: Try to write a proof by induction... *Base* case with $\varphi$ atomic, i.e. $P(x)$ (for simplicity, only a unary predicate). Assume for contradiction that [corrected the typo] for all a∈A ... and A,β⊭P. Take the element c such that β(x)=c, so that β[c/x]=β. Then A,β[c/x]⊭P, so that we have some a∈A for which A,β[a/xn]⊭P. Contradiction! So $\mathcal A, \beta \vDash P$.

Comment: *Induction step* (to be splitted into sub-cases): (i) for $\lnot \psi$ as $\varphi$. Again, with the same approach take the element c such that β(x)=c, so that β[c/x]=β. Then $\mathcal A,β[c/x] \nvDash \lnot \psi$, that is $\mathcal A,β[c/x] \vDash \psi$. But this fact again contradicts the assumption that for all a∈A, $\mathcal A,β[a/x] \nvDash \lnot \psi$. So...

Comment: Now compare: what are the difference of the detailed cases wrt to "general" one above???